# Jmeter gets Apache lost db connection

Tags: php, oracle, apache-2.2, jmeter

I have a web app that makes to many ajax requests (update data with a grid).

When I use JMeter to make a stress test with 20 threads and 10 loops, my web application canno't connect to the database (Oracle) in the 3th sample.

My server has the next configuration:

```
Physical Server: Dell r710 , 01 processor Xeon 2.66 Ghz 06 Cores, RAM 32 GB, 05 Disk of 500GB

Virtual Server: 01 Processor Xeon 04 Cores, 03 GB RAM, 36 GB of hard disk.

soporte@olivo:~$ df -h
S.ficheros            Tamaño Usado  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/sda3             5,6G  2,5G  2,8G  48% /
none                  2,0G  172K  2,0G   1% /dev
none                  2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /dev/shm
none                  2,0G  916K  2,0G   1% /var/run
none                  2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /var/lock
none                  2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1              92M   26M   62M  30% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1    28G  7,5G   19G  30% /var
soporte@olivo:~$

APACHE:
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)

PHP:
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)

SO:
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

Welcome to the Ubuntu Server!
 * Documentation:  http://www.ubuntu.com/server/doc

  System information as of Tue Dec 27 17:15:34 PET 2011

  System load: 0.1               Memory usage: 17%   Processes:       134
  Usage of /:  44.6% of 5.50GB   Swap usage:   0%    Users logged in: 1

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

Also, this Web App make many requests via ajax in the background, so when there are 10 or more users these ajax requests that are made in the background makes the application falls (subsequent connections gets an ORA-12520 error).

I would know how to avoid the server to stop connecting to the database when a lot of users (20 or more) are conected at same time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a coding question or a server question? The answer to both might be to use database connection pooling, but how you do that depends on too many variables for me to answer based on what you've told us so far.